# EF Core error: "All entity types in a hierarchy need to have the same ownership status"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the two entities I'm trying to configure in EF, `Casino` and `Bonus`

```
[Table("Casino")]
public partial class Casino
{
    private ICollection<Bonus> _bonuses;

    public ICollection<Bonus> Bonuses
    {
        get { return _bonuses; }
        set { _bonuses = value; }
    }
}
```

```
[Table("Bonus")]
[Owned]
public abstract class Bonus
{
    private Casino _casino;

    public Casino Casino
    {
        get { return _casino; }
        set { _casino = value; }
    }
}
```

`Bonus` is abstract and there are several bonus types that inherit from `Bonus` e.g. `BonusMatch` and `BonusNoDeposit`.

```
[Owned]
public partial class BonusMatch : Bonus
{
    // Match bonus properties
}
```

When I run a unit test to create a new record in the database, I am getting the [following exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.corestrings.derivedentityownershipmismatch?view=efcore-7.0):

> System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to set 'Bonus' as the base type for entity type 'BonusMatch' because 'BonusMatch' is configured as owned, while 'Bonus' is non-owned. All entity types in a hierarchy need to have the same ownership status. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-owned for more information and examples.

It seems that somewhere where EF Core is seeing `Bonus` as non-owned, but I can't find anywhere else to mark it as owned.

I can't see where my configuration is incorrect based on the MS [ownership](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#collections-of-owned-types) docs

```
public class CasinoConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Casino>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Casino> modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.OwnsMany(
            c => c.Bonuses, b =>
                { 
                    b.WithOwner(b => b.Casino).HasForeignKey("CasinoId");
                    b.Property<int>("Id");
                    b.HasKey("Id");
                }
            );
    }
}
```

```
public class BonusConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Bonus>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Bonus> modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.HasDiscriminator(d => d.SecondaryBonusType)
            .HasValue(typeof(BonusMatch), BonusTypes.Match)
            .HasValue(typeof(BonusFreeplay), BonusTypes.Freeplay)
            .HasValue(typeof(BonusNoDeposit), BonusTypes.NoDeposit)
            .HasValue(typeof(BonusPostWager), BonusTypes.PostWager)
            .HasValue(typeof(BonusCashback), BonusTypes.Cashback)
        ;

       modelBuilder
            .HasOne(b => b.Casino) // 
            .WithMany(c => c.Bonuses)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

The abstract `Bonus` class is decorated with the `[Owned]` attribute (which doesn't appear to make a difference) AND the EF config says a `Casino` **OwnsMany** `Bonuses` yet the exception is telling me that `Bonus` is non-owned. I don't see how else I can mark `Bonus` as owned.

Comment: It's currently not supported. "Current shortcomings
Owned entity types cannot have inheritance hierarchies" from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities

Comment: Thanks @StevePy. That seems like a pretty massive shortcoming

Comment: Welcome to EF Core / .Net Core / Open Source.  It'll get in there eventually, or just linger in the "too hard" bucket. :)